# Calling jQuery's DOM ready function from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to call jQuery's `$(document).ready` function from within another Javascript function? I have a button, which when clicked should call the jQuery DOM ready function. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are calling it from another javascript function, drop the `$(document).ready` part

```
function f1(){
 $('#idhere').something;
}
```

or if you want to call a function only when the document is ready, put the function call inside `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function f1(){
  //do something here
 }
});
```

But you are not taking advantage of jquery's full functionality here. If you want to associate an onclick event with an element, you can do it like so:

```
<button id='button1'></button>
```

In the js file:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
 //do the onclick sequence here
});
```